# Date value recorded as 0000-00-00 in Mysql database from html form

Tags: php, mysql, date, textbox

I know the same question has been asked several times but I cant seem to wrap my head around it.I have done all the solutions I have found but its not working in my case.'Date'is being recorded as 0000-00-00 within the Mysql database instead of a proper date.Here is the PHP code.`

```
// initialize variables

$Vehicle_name = "";
$Vehicle_make = "";
$Vehicle_color="";
$Number_plate = "";
$Driver_name = "";
$Number_of_passengers = "";
$Date = "";
$Time = "";
$Security = "";


$id = 0;
$update = false;

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $Vehicle_name = $_POST['Vehicle_name'];
    $Vehicle_make = $_POST['Vehicle_make'];
    $Vehicle_color = $_POST['Vehicle_color'];
    $Number_plate = $_POST['Number_plate'];
    $Driver_name = $_POST['Driver_name'];
    $Number_of_passengers = $_POST['Number_of_passengers'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date '];
    $Time = $_POST['Time'];
    $Security = $_POST['Security'];


    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO vehicle (Vehicle_name,Vehicle_make,Vehicle_color,Number_plate,Driver_name,Number_of_passengers,Date,Time,Security ) VALUES ('$Vehicle_name','$Vehicle_make','$Vehicle_color','$Number_plate','$Driver_name','$Number_of_passengers','$Date','$Time','$Security ')"); 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Car registered"; 
    header('location: welcome.php');
}`.
```

Here is the date textbox code also.

`<div class="input-group">
<label>Date :</label>
<input type="date" name="Date" value=""  required="yes"  >
</div>`.

I have spent so much time trying to figure it out but all in vain,please help.Regards.

Comment: `$Date = $_POST['Date '];` <-- there is a rouge space here, after `Date`.  This could be the reason the date is coming up null/empty.

Comment: check date format...mysql date format is "YYYY-mm-dd"

Comment: Note: please don’t ever put values from the user into SQL strings. Use parameters/prepared statements. It will save you a lot of trouble. Just try giving driver’s name as John O’Malley in your current code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is space in your key

```
$Date = $_POST['Date '];
```

change it to

```
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
```

The way you are passing parameter would lead to **SQL injection**. Please read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

If your database field's datatype is **date** then you can change below line of code

```
$Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```

If your database field's datatype is **datetime** then you can change below line of code

```
$Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```

Here i can see you are separating time in another field then you can change below line of code

```
$Time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Time']));
```